# Pipes in CLOUDERA (C++)

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, pipe, hadoop-yarn, cloudera

I am working in Cloudera with java from last few months. I would like to use C++ in my future project.
it will be great if you guide me how to install Pipes library on Hadoop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually need to install anything else on the server side.  Just build your C++ application and run it as you would a Java Hadoop client.  [This post](http://cs.smith.edu/dftwiki/index.php/Hadoop_Tutorial_2.2_--_Running_C%2B%2B_Programs_on_Hadoop) has a nice basic example of executing a job via pipes.

Comment: By any chance you know how to use cleanup method(java) in Cpp

Comment: It is very similar to the way you do it in Java (different syntax of course), because [Mapper()](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Mapper.html) has the same set of methods regardless of language.

Comment: So I assume it is same for reducers as well!